# Hindi Font Problem in Chrome

Tags: firefox, fonts, google-chrome

I am using Google Chrome. I am facing problem in using Hindi News. which shows bullets instead of proper hindi text. but this same thing is not happening with Firefox it shows Hindi font .

when i use https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Fonts this in Firefox

**Fonts In firefox**

[image: Font in Firefox]

**Fonts in Chrome**

[image: Font in Chrome]

I used this site for solving this problem its tell me to modify [.fonts.conf](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B_kUTKwYPKsUNTE0ZDBhZWQtYWM4Yi00OTA4LWE1YTktOWI2Y2IzNTBhNWI3&hl=en_GB) file
I'm currently working on font settings in XML (.fonts.conf). I noticed that after installing msttcorefonts things don't look quite as good in Firefox anymore. Most web pages request Arial which doesn't get hinted and anti-aliased too nicely, especially on LCD screens. I personally prefer the "sharp" non-anti-aliased look. i hate the new look which comes from this conf.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 32bit . the Font i am using in this version  of Ubuntu  are the latest . or i have to update my fonts . is there any new font look in Ubuntu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hindi font rendering problem in Chrome is already well-documented. There has been a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/856736) filed against this problem.

A [workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/856736/comments/5) has been suggested in the bug report, but I consider it too drastic as it involves deleting a couple of fonts. Instead, we can achieve the same effect by renaming those fonts.

Enter these commands in a terminal:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSerif.ttf.backup
sudo mv /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSans.ttf /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSans.ttf.backup
```

The Google Chrome page after the above modification:

[image]

Comment: Rather than delete the fonts, I first just prefixed them with "xxx" to get xxxFreeSerif.ttf and xxxFreeSans.ttf. That didn't work. Still got the empty boxes. So I copied them to my desktop (in case I ever need them) and then deleted them from the folder. That worked perfectly.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of deleting the fonts, I have recommended renaming it.

Answer (score 0):

My machine Hindi fonts were sometimes overlapping each other in Chrome browser and this was mostly happening in Facebook site. I changed my font to ARIAL UNICODE MS in Chrome's setting and the issue was resolved.

Hope it helps somebody with similar issue.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this problem by adding the **Hindi Font Pack** extension to Chrome:

[Hindi Font Pack, Offered by: knjhaveri](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hindi-font-pack/dkdokiobifblgnlcebbnmfkllhbdcokl/reviews?hl=en-US)

Simply click "Add to Chrome" to install extension.

Comment: I am not sure the original problem from 2012 still exits in 2019. I can access BBC Hindi from both Firefox and Chrome just fine without any font packs.