# Google Chrome not rendering Kannada correctly?

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, fonts

I am facing a problem in viewing web pages with [kannada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannada_language). I tried re-installing Chrome but still have the problem.

[image]

Comment: Hi, please provide a couple of links people can test. Also, mention which browsers render these sites correctly. And what is the image meant to convey? Is there some context?

Comment: Also look at [Hindi Font Problem in Chrome](http://askubuntu.com/q/97639/25656) and [Facebook Bangla font Problem in google chrome](http://askubuntu.com/q/111519/25656) for how people have reported problems with other languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed ttf-kannada-fonts_0.5.11ubuntu1_all  package from the software channel
And kannada fonts in websites like Facebook and http://kannada.oneindia.in/  are working just fine.

I have Lubuntu 12.04 OS and inbuilt Chrome Browser.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings -> Web content  -> Set all type of fonts to Lohit Kannada
it will fix the issue immediately